# Bing site scan: Avoid Error 403 if index.html is missing the root domain name

Tags: htaccess, apache, 301-redirect, 403-forbidden

I have a website with the following domain name:

`https://example.com` (there is no `index.html` in the root domain name)

I have the following redirect based on language detection in `.htaccess`:

`https://example.com` > `https://example.com/en/index.html` (for English language)
`https://example.com` > `https://example.com/fr/index.html` (for French language)

The user is redirected correctly, but Bing site scan returns error 403 due to the missing `index.html` in the root domain `https://example.com`. This means that Bing's crawler fails indexing the website. Google's crawler is not affected and can index the website properly.

What are the best SEO friendly solutions to this problem I am experiencing with Bing?

That is my current .htaccess redirect/rewrite

```
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Detect browser's language
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/en/ [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/fr/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What is the language detection code that you are using in `.htaccess`?  Can you [edit] your question to include it?

Comment: Hi, I post the code in the Question for clarity. Here it would be hard to read. BTW: did you receive my reply in private with all references about EU GDPR?

Comment: It is always preferable to edit your questions and answers here rather than providing updates in the comments.  Your reply was received.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion/recommendation regarding the issue detailed in the question?

Comment: How is Googlebot finding the fr site?  When it crawls, it sends `Accept-language: en`.  I'd expect Googlebot to be ignoringc your fr site entirely unless you have links to it from somewhere else.

Comment: through robots.txt and sitemap.xml

Comment: What do you have in `robots.txt` that helps the search engines find the appropriate URLs?

Comment: In the robots.txt files there is the sitemap.xml which provides the URLs list of all webpages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> # Detect browser's language
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
> RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/en/ [L,R=301] 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
> RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/fr/ [L,R=301]
> ```
>
> The user is redirected correctly

The user is only redirected "correctly" if `en` or `fr` is the user's *primary* language (or rather, if the language code appears at the start of the `Accept-Language` header). This is unreliable (even when it "works") for a number reasons:

- The primary language is not guaranteed to appear at the start of the `Accept-Language` header.
- The `Accept-Langauge` header can contain a series of *weighted* languages - which is not easily determined by a simple regex.
- If the user's browser is set to another "primary" language and `en` or `fr` is only a secondary language then the redirect will fail.
- The user is using someone else's machine where the primary language is different to what they understand.

It's possible that Bing is not sending an `Accept-Language` header at all (or `en` or `fr` is not at the start of the `Accept-Language` header) so the redirect is failing and a 403 Forbidden response is served (since there is no index document). You would need to set a "default" language.

For example, if `en` is to be the default:

```
# Detect browser's language
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(en|fr) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/%1/ [L,R=302]

# Default to "en"
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/en/ [L,R=302]
```

This at least avoids the 403.

The `%1` backreference contains the language code as captured in the preceding *condition*, ie. the value at the start of the `Accept-Language` header - if `en` or `fr`.

Also note the `302`, as opposed to `301`. Language redirects should not be 301 (permanent) - it should be 302 (temporary). By making it a 301 then the user is unable to change the language since the 301 redirect is cached persistently by the browser.

However, other search engines (such as Googlebot) generally only send an `Accept-Language: en` header so they are *always* redirected to the English version. Although, you are only redirecting the homepage (root directory), so providing the `fr` language version is referenced in other ways (Sitemap, hreflang, etc) then it should still be crawlable.

However, there is potentially another issue....

> <sup>(From your [cross-site question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76337029/bing-site-scan-avoid-error-403-if-index-html-is-missing-the-root-domain-name))</sup>
> There is a structure like the following: example.com/en , example.com/en/sub1, example.com/en sub2, example.com/en/etc

If a request is received for `/sub1` or `/sub2` (no language code) then should this be redirected or result in a 404 (or 403)? (Currently the later, since the above redirect will not match, which is perhaps desirable. Requests for `/sub1` or `/sub2` without a language code might be *rare* anyway.)

Users should be given the option of changing the language (since the `Accept-Language` header is not reliable - as discussed above). So, if the user selects another language (which is perhaps then stored in a cookie by your script) then this can be used to override the auto-redirection.

For example, if the cookie used is called `lang` with a value of either `en` or `fr` (if the user has chosen this) then you could add the following *before* the above language redirects:

```
# Redirect user if previously selected a language (overriding default)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (?:^|;|\s)lang=(en|fr)(?:$|;)
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/%1/ [L,R=302]

# Language redirect follows...
```

The `%1` backreference contains the language code as captured in the preceding *condition*, ie. the value of the `lang` cookie (if any).

Comment: I'm not sure how the subdirectories figuer into this.  `^$` in the rewrite rules should match exactly the home page URL, not `/sub1`.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, and maybe that's desirable / for the better.

Comment: It is never a good idea to auto redirect from one language to another, so making sure that auto-redirects don't include `/fr` or `/en` better for sure.